# Aligning font-size across browsers

Tags: html, css, width

Two `div`s, one floating left, one right.
The first contains text (which is static) and has no fixed width, the other has a fixed width.

Is there a way to make the widths sum up to a certain value (eg. width of a containing `div`)? Preferably a `CSS` only solution.

The problem is different browsers give the text slightly different sizes, so the first div varies in its width. Setting a fixed width to the first div breaks it in the browsers which would have it longer. I can make it the longest I find, but I might have missed a browser, or the issue might return with a newer version.

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/JcfGN/3/embedded/result/

(In chrome there is a gap between the `div`s, in IE 10 they overlap. I would like them to meet nicely)

**Addition:**

The same problem with `height` has been solved using `line-height`. Is there something parallel to `line-width`?

Comment: Maybe save yourself some time and use something like http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ which is part of http://html5boilerplate.com/ and maybe you can take the parts of Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ like the grid system that you might want to use

Comment: You think that can solve it? If so - which CSS line does it?